# How to create a simple checkbox in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, checkbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checkbox in IPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650131/checkbox-in-iphone-application)

I want to create a simple checkbox with 2 values and save this, how can I make that?

Thanks.

Comment: please search before you post.

Comment: Warning: the native component for a toggle widget is the UISwitch. The accepted answer implements a windows style checkbox with an UIButton.

Comment: You can simply set the appropriate images from SF symbol for normal and selected state. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392377/1311902 for detailed answer

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yeah, no checkbox for you in iOS (-:

Here, this is what I did to create a checkbox:

```
UIButton *checkbox;
BOOL checkBoxSelected;
checkbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,20,20)];
// 20x20 is the size of the checkbox that you want
// create 2 images sizes 20x20 , one empty square and
// another of the same square with the checkmark in it
// Create 2 UIImages with these new images, then:

[checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notselectedcheckbox.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedcheckbox.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[checkbox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedcheckbox.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
checkbox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES;
[checkbox addTarget:(nullable id) action:(nonnull SEL) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)];
[self.view addSubview:checkbox];
```

Now in the target method do the following:

```
-(void)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    checkBoxSelected = !checkBoxSelected; /* Toggle */
    [checkbox setSelected:checkBoxSelected];
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Just a very very very small comment. Don't forget the @ before the strings: @"notselectedcheckbox.png".

Comment: and also if you have multiple buttons you can use this on your taget method `UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
 if([btn isSelected]){
  [btn setSelected:NO];
 }else{
  [btn setSelected:YES];
 }`

Comment: the two lines where you define the highlighted state aren't needed! they just glitch the checkbox (atleast in iOS5). :)

Comment: You can do without graphics if you use this approach instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2615036/1431728.

Comment: I think using setImage is better than setBackgroundImage, because the image will not stretched if we increased the size of button to increase the selection area

Comment: Added `button states` using interface builder. Worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: You can also just use switches. I didnt think of that at first. -.-

Answer (score 37):

On iOS there is the switch UI component instead of a checkbox, look into the `UISwitch` class.
The property `on` (boolean) can be used to determine the state of the slider and about the saving of its state: That depends on how you save your other stuff already, its just saving a boolean value.

Comment: I prefer the UISwitch as well, as it's native, optimised and easily customisable. The first answer is also great, but for me (and that's only personal pref) there's no need to re-invent the wheels if not needed.

Comment: switch is of no use if we want to allow users to select multiple choices.

Comment: @Hiren Prajapati: Why? In case you need to get multiple boolean choices you'd use multiple UISwitch elements, as it is done in the main Preference application. The only culprit with using a UISwitch instead of a checkmark is just aesthetically/representative for those cases when the UI should convey a "Done/Not Done" state for something.

Comment: Unfortunately when you do have a list of items and you want a user to select some of them, a switch is much less aesthetically pleasing

Comment: In iOS 14.0, there is now a "UISwitchStyle" property with a "UISwitchStyleCheckbox" appearance for UISwitch, showing a traditional check box.

Comment: @fishinear The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/style/checkbox) say "UISwitch.Style.checkbox is only available to Mac apps built with Mac Catalyst that use the UIUserInterfaceIdiom.mac idiom."

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Darn, you are correct. Weird that they state "Availability iOS 14.0+" when it does not work on iOS 14, though. You can use the style, but it does not show up as a checkbox...