# Deleting multiple cells from the table view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have table view which is loading from the database having customize cell. On button checkBox should appeared on each cell of table view . After this i just want to delete the checked items from the table view. How it can be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have an array to populate.

So you must delete elements from the array 
an make a reloadData likeThis

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: for example you can add a checkBox as in Mail application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368196/how-create-simple-checkbox to manage a checkBox

Answer (score 1):

```
Here recording data array is a array of dictionary in which there is a key which keep track of which button is checked or which is unchecked. on clicking Delete button you can use below mentioned concept for deleting more than open array at a go :

USE THIS CONCEPT : 

    - (IBAction)deleteClicked:(id)sender 
    {
        for(int index = 0 ; index < [recordingDataArray count] ; index++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *item = [recordingDataArray objectAtIndex:index];
            BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checkStatus"] boolValue];
            if(checked)
            {
                [recordingDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                index--;
            }
        }
        [self.recordingTblView reloadData];
    }

THANKS & REGARDS,
GAUTAM TIWARI
```