# How do I create a checkbox in iOS Titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

How would I create a checkbox with Titanium for iOS?

Comment: You would have to make your own one e.g create an square view and attach a clickhandler on it which toggles the background color and sets a checked flag

Comment: thanks for your comment :) can u give me some example? i've tried to set checked flag value but it won't change.. do you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an very simplified example of how you could do something similar

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow()

function createCheckbox (specs) {
    if(typeof specs != "object")
        specs = {};
    specs.width = specs.width || 25
    specs.backgroundColor = specs.unCheckedColor || "white"
    specs.height = specs.height || 25
    specs.border = specs.border || 1
    specs.borderColor = specs.borderColor || "silver"
    var viw = Ti.UI.createView(specs)
    
    function togglecheck () {
        if(!viw.checked) {
            viw.checked = true;
            viw.backgroundColor = specs.checkedColor || "green"
        }
        else {
            viw.checked = false;
            viw.backgroundColor = specs.unCheckedColor || "white"
        }           
    }
    viw.addEventListener("click",togglecheck)
    
    return viw
}

var checkbox = createCheckbox({})

win.add(checkbox)
```

You could also use background images to display an checkmark on the view
or add a smaller view on a slightly bigger one and only give the inner view a border color and display an checkmark image on the outer view

Hope this points you in the right direction

---

Edit: Here is an example with an image,
though i really would create a new one (obviously transparent)  because this one looks really bad ^^
anyway this way a checkboxc with images could work

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow()
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor("#FFF")
function createCheckbox (specs,checkboxspecs,image) {
    
    if(typeof checkboxspecs != "object")
        checkboxspecs = {};
    checkboxspecs.width = checkboxspecs.width || 25
    checkboxspecs.backgroundColor = checkboxspecs.unCheckedColor || "white"
    checkboxspecs.height = checkboxspecs.height || 25
    checkboxspecs.border = checkboxspecs.border || 1
    checkboxspecs.borderColor = checkboxspecs.borderColor || "silver"
    var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image:image || "acheckbox.gif",
        height:checkboxspecs.height * 1.5,
        bottom:3 + checkboxspecs.height * 0.5,
        left:3 + checkboxspecs.width * 0.5,
        opacity:0
    })  
    
    var viw = Ti.UI.createView(checkboxspecs)
    specs.width =  checkboxspecs.width * 1.5;
    specs.height = checkboxspecs.height * 1.5;
    
    var outerview = Ti.UI.createView({
        width: specs.width * 1.5,
        height: specs.height * 1.5,
    })
    var clickview = Ti.UI.createView({
        width:checkboxspecs.width,
        height:checkboxspecs.height
    })
    outerview.add(viw)
    outerview.add(imageView)
    outerview.add(clickview)
    
    function togglecheck () {
        if(!viw.checked) {
            viw.checked = true;
            imageView.opacity = 1;
            
        }
        else {
            viw.checked = false;
            imageView.opacity = 0;
        }           
    }
    clickview.addEventListener("click",togglecheck)
    return outerview
}

var checkbox = createCheckbox({},{
    width:20,
    height:20,
    borderRadius:3,
    border:2
},"checkbox.gif")

win.add(checkbox)
```

win.open()

Save the image as "checkbox.gif" and put it in the Resources folder
(really, create a new one)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368196/how-create-simple-checkbox), there are no checkboxes in iOS. You probably want to use the [UI switch](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.1/Titanium.UI.Switch-object).

Comment: thanks for your answer Marcus.. i really needs checkbox style like checkbox in iphone email.. do u have other suggestion?

Comment: In that case, take a look at Glutamats comment.