# how to add checkboxes on iOS

Tags: iphone

I want to add checkboxes and have a title for each checkbox and have if certain boxes are checked then it displays certain texts like

if box 1 then displays text1

if box 2 is selected then displays text2

Comment: I have created by own UI element called `UICheckBox` that basically has two different images one when checked and another when it isn't checked, you could also do this using a custom `UIButton` by changing the image for the different states one for selected and one for normal.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you actually stuck?

Comment: check this ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368196/how-create-simple-checkbox

Comment: accept one of answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this ,

```
UIButton *buttonCheckbox = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 12,20, 20)];  

[buttonCheckbox addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleButton:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)toggleButton: (id) sender
{
   UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*)sender;

   NSLog(@"%d",tappedButton.tag);
   if([tappedButton.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]])
  {
   [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkbox-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
    else
  {
   [sender  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find on [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/checkbox) some custom controls that implement checkboxes.

For example `SSCheckBoxView` is one of them. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSCheckBoxView)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for UISwitch, it has the same functionality with checkbox but a different appearance. Otherwise you need to create your own checkbox possibly by customizing a UIButton.

To get updated when UISwitch's value changes you need to hook up its valueChanged event to an action.

```
-(IBAction) valueChanged:(UISwitch *) sender
{
     if(sender.on)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```