# Image Gallery with checkboxes on photos

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to create a similar gallery interface including a checkbox which selects the corresponding image. I could create the gallery with UICollectionViewCell. Now wants to add the checkboxes for each image. Can anyone guide me how should i continue? I am planning to continue  with  a check box image , On touch event etc..Is there any built in controls or templates? Can anyone provide some useful links for me to continue.
[image]
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Should give you this link : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368196/how-create-simple-checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368196/how-create-simple-checkbox)

Comment: https://github.com/chute/photo-picker-plus-ios check this library

Answer (score 1):

**First way**

Just using an `UIImageView` and settings a state to the `UICollectionViewCell`. According to the status you have to change the `UIImage` inside the `UIImageView`.

**SecondWay**

Just using an `UIButton` with two `UIImage`: one for the normal state and one for the selected state. This probably aggravate the touch on the cell.

*IMHO...*

I suggest to use the first way. i.e when you select a photo you are in the **editing** mode: the touch select the photo and not show it in full screen mode. So, when you are in the editing modeyou can switch the behavior for the touch.