# How to show tickmark on image when it is selected

Tags: iphone, ipad

i want to show a tick mark on each picture which is selected. i have no idea about that.can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

place a uibutton programmatically on the same location ad of selected picture .The button will be a custom button having transparent tick.png image.

Comment: thanks aman.But i think it is not a good way to do this .i think it is a built-in property to show tick mark when picture is selected.But thanks for your view.if you can suggest any thingelse.please

Comment: if you explain more about your problem, means what you specifically wants , then i could give you more suggestion in good way

Comment: yah.i have a  project in which user open a photo library select image from there. As he select image i have to put them in an array.but when he select image i have also show a tick mark on the selected picture .so,that it look like user select the picture. i have done all work but i am confuse about how to show a tick mark when user select the picture.

Comment: Here is a librar that do the same thing as neede by you , get the code from here  https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: thanks aman. iam studying it. it look like benificial .if any doubt is persist .i will take your help. i think you don't mind.

Comment: anytime. brother, do accept the answer , i analyzed the code and it does the same thing as you want

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use `UIButton` and two different set of images for more have a look to the below post,

Blog tutorial.

http://weheartgames.com/2009/06/simple-iphone-checkbox/

SO post,

[Checkbox in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650131/checkbox-in-iphone-application)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40592-any-way-make-uibutton-latch.html