# What is the closest analog to Cocoa's `NSSwitchButton` checkbox in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, uikit

What is the closest analog to Cocoa's `NSSwitchButton` checkbox in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is the same "lightswitch-style" ON/OFF button that is used in preferences.

[image: UISwitch image]

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-switch-control-uiswitch-control-tutorial/) on using `UISwitch` on iOS.

Comment: Is this the only closest substitution?  I was hoping something close to the checkbox.  Since I will need to have about 8 of them for user to check.

Comment: I'm afraid so. However, it is pretty easy to reproduce a more traditional checkbox using a `UIButton` and supplying two different images (one for checked, one for unchecked). See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650131/checkbox-in-iphone-application

Comment: It looks like the old checkbox will be missed!  Thanks.