# how to change the button image inside the table cell while clicking the button in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a tableview in my application. I created a button inside the table cell and assigned a background image to it. I wanted to change the background image when i click that button. I assigned an action for the button like this

```
-(void)goodBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    [goodBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But, the image is not getting replaced with the new image. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Do you want the background to change permanently, or only during the tap?

Comment: I wanted to use this button as check box. If i click once it as to changed to check mark image an if i double click it, it as to remove the check mark image to plain image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox in IPhone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650131/checkbox-in-iphone-application)

Comment: my button action is not working inside the table cell

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your image is actually there.

```
-(void)goodBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"];
    NSAssert(img, @"Image shouldn't be nil");
    [goodBtn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
-(void)goodBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through all the subviews and locate your button then change background image

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    for (UIView *sub in cell.subviews) {

        if([sub isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
          UIButton * button=[[UIButton alloc] init];
          button=sub;
          [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

    }

}
```