# In code test if UIButtonTypeSystem is defined for iOS6

Tags: ios, uibutton

UIButtonTypeSystem is not defined in iOS 6

if I put the following code will crash the app ?

```
if(appSetting.iOSVersion>=7){
    photo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
}else{
    photo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
}
```

How to code to to check if UIButtonTypeSystem defined and prevent crashing?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support iOS 6 then use UIButtonTypeRoundedRect instead of UIButtonTypeSystem. It will then work under both iOS 6 and 7. 
In the docs it states:

> UIButtonTypeSystem A system style button, such as those shown in navigation bars and toolbars. Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: I try using UIButtonTypeRoundedRect in the code, when it is iOS 7 device. the image does not shown in the button. It shows blue button instead. Some thread recommend to use UIButtonTypeSystem , it works. In iOS 6 , it crash.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133465/setting-uibutton-image-results-in-blue-button-in-ios-7