# *.png image changes its color in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, png

I want to set image in UIButton. It has orange color. Then I insert it like this:

```
[cell.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Oval 135 Copy + Triangle 1 Copy.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I launch my app this image changes its color, how it is possible and how this problem may be solved? I add simulator picture and photo:

[image]

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18187058/1106035

Comment: @PareshNavadiya Yeah! That's it, thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your button using `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` ? If so, the button will automatically try to tint your image with the `tintColor` value of the button.

If you want to opt out of this behavior, you can do it like so :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Oval 135 Copy + Triangle 1 Copy.png"];
UIImage *originalImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[cell.playButton setImage:originalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Alternatively you can also create your button using `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`, but its behavior will be slightly different, so choose the option that works best for you.