# How to set image on button

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to swift and I've searched different places and couldn't really find anything helpful.

I am in this case that I pick an image from `UIImagePickerController` when pressing on the button:

```
@IBAction func chooseImage(_ sender: Any){}
```

which works and I can access the photo library and choose an image but..
the thing is that I want to set it to the button image.
I save the image to:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // this works with an UIimageView.image but I can't get it to work with the button

    ???.image = image
```

I believe the way to do it is to say; `button.ImageView.image = image` and this can only be done by creating a variable called `UIButton`!??
and then I can set

```
button.ImageView.image = image
```

otherwise I can't enter the method `ImageView.image`

But the thing is that chooseImage is the same button I use for the action of receiving the image... So can I both make a @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! and @IBAction on the same button??
Well I tried and created both a

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```

and

```
@IBAction func chooseImage(_ sender: Any) {

button.imageView.image = image
}
```

but nothing happened It might sound confusing,but there is two questions. Is it possible to do it this way? and if yes, why isn't the picture being shown when doing

```
 button.imageView.image = image?
```

and if not please tell me what im doing wrong :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    someButton.setImage(imagenew, for: .normal)
```

There is a setimage method for UIButton. you can also set image as background image. There is a method called `setbackgroundImage`.

Comment: Yes but how do I acces the setImage?? 

can I create both a
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

and

IBAction func chooseImage(_ sender: Any) {

on the same button?

Comment: @StrawHat yes, you can create both an outlet and action

Comment: thanks! I tried and it worked somewhat, now that I choose an image. it shows all blue... (the button image)?? it dosen't set the correct image

Comment: Thanks a lot!
setbackgroundImage did it :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
button.setImage(image, for: .normal) // Swift 3
```

Comment: es but how do I acces the setImage?? can I create both a @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! and IBAction func chooseImage(_ sender: Any) { on the same button?

Comment: Thanks! I tried and it worked somewhat, now that I choose an image. it shows all blue... (the button image)?? it dosen't set the correct image

Comment: Check this solution, this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133465/setting-uibutton-image-results-in-blue-button-in-ios-7

Comment: It worked by setbackgroundImage as Ray_soham told about..
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use **setImage**() method to set the **foreground image** of a button. However, if your buttons are all blue, that's because there is a feature for images called "**Rendering Mode**" you should be aware of, please refer to [Template Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7) for more information:

```
button.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
```