# Create Checkbox using Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to Objective-C so i am mostly using Storyboard, Someone Please tell me how to create a `checkbox` using Xcode in iOS.

Comment: You need to create UITableView with multiple selection.

Comment: how to do that could you please elaborate.

Comment: How do we determine what version of xCode this question was asked under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CheckBox is not available in object library**. You can use third party library for that purpose or you can create it by your self.

There is the working code for checkbox.

create a class level variable and property of button in @inteface

```
@interface testViewController (){
    BOOL checkBoxSelected;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkBox;

@end
```

in viewdidload set images for the button states.

```
 [_checkBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxUnChecked.png"]
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBoxChecked.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and after create a button action in that button Action.

```
checkBoxSelected = !checkBoxSelected; /* Toggle */
    [_checkBox setSelected:checkBoxSelected];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

`UISwitch` is the standard control used in iOS for indicating an on/off, selected/unselected state. Why not use that?

Comment: what if i have to use agree condition and before that i have to use check terms and conditions.

Answer (score 3):

UISwitch is the standard control used in IOS applications for making binary choices but if you want to use checkbox you can create a UIButton

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *CheckBox;
- (IBAction)CheckBoxClick:(id)sender
```

and change its background image on click event of UIButton

```
- (IBAction)CheckBoxClick:(id)sender {
    if(!checked){
        [_CheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = YES;
    }
    else if(checked){
        [_CheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked = NO;
    }
}
```

also there are more detailed answers to this question at

[How to create a simple checkbox in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368196/how-create-simple-checkbox)

and if you dont want to use images you can check the following

[Checkbox in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650131/checkbox-in-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create Prototype cell in UITableView.

2) Add one button inside the cell and set button style to Custom.

3) Set the image for checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

ios language doesn't use checkbox controller.
but you are use checkbox that you are inport two image select & unselect

Step 1> Create button and set image.

Step 2> Create button touch object method and put if condition for check & uncheck.
for example:

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
   if (btn.tag == 0) {
       btn.tag = 1;
      //set image checked.
   }
   else{
       btn.tag = 0;
      //set image unchecked.
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to subclass the UIButton class. By design, Objective-C favors composition over inheritance.

UIButton is a subclass of UIControl, which has a selected property. You can use this property to toggle the on/off behaviour of a checkbox, just the same way a UISwitch does.

You can attach an action to the button's touched up inside event, and perform the toggling in there, something like this:

```
// when you setup your button, set an image for the selected and normal states

[myCheckBoxButton setImage:nonCheckedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myCheckBoxButton setImage:nonCheckedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

- (void)myCheckboxToggle:(id)sender
{
    myCheckboxButton.selected = !myCheckboxButton.selected; // toggle the selected property, just a simple BOOL
}
```